# wrong props in dynamically rendered components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm rendering my components from props like this:

```
  const submissions = this.props.submissions != null && this.props.submissions.map((item,i) => {
      return <SubmissionListItem key={i} submission={item} >
      </SubmissionListItem>
    })
```

props are in its place for every component. But inside the child component, when I dispatch an action to call an API, inside my componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) the props are changed always to the first component that was rendered

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.boostId != null && this.props.boostId != nextProps.boostId) {
            this.setState({ RedirectTo: "boost" });
        }
    }
```

I do have a unique identifier on the component rendering so this behavior is strange.
Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Dont see a boostId prop passed to SubmissionListItem

Comment: @ssk - mapStateToProps - it is being binded using the reducer. But anyway, this is not related to the problem itself, you can ignore what's inside the componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: post full component code. along with how you are connecting it with redux store.